# PHPExcel - Each cell into an array

Tags: multidimensional-array, phpexcel

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is read an entire excel spreadsheet and update a database using it. My thought is to create an array in the following format:

```
    $array['row_number']['column_name']['cell_value']
```

Then use that array to populate the database accordingly. I am not really sure where to start on this one to be honest. My PHP is decent enough but my knowledge of PHPExcel is nothing short of minimal.

Could someone point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Consider using PHPExcel's toArray() method: most of the examples in the `/Documentation/Examples/Reader` folder use this method

Comment: @MarkBaker is there any specific documentation on the toArray() method?

Comment: Aside from the API documentation, no! But there's a whole host of examples that show its use